# Are Objects created in an AIR native extension garbage collected? (desktop C++)

Tags: c++, actionscript, air, garbage-collection, air-native-extension

If in my ANE I do something like this:

```
FREObject createObject(FREContext ctx, void* funcData, uint32_t argc, FREObject argv[])
{
    FREObject ret, exception;
    FRENewObject( (const uint8_t*)"Object", 0, NULL, &ret, &exception );
    return ret;
}
```

Is the returned object (`ret`) garbage collected by AIR?

Comment: I won't answer, since I don't know for absolute certain, but until someone with more definitive knowledge about this answers, I'll just say that, as far as I know, AS3 is pretty good about automatic garbage collection.